# How to turn Python integer into datetime

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple PyQt GUI which gives values which I would like to turn into a datetime format.

At the moment it is printing

```
201011
```

Whereas I would like it to print

```
2010,1,1
```

Here is the PyQt code,

```
*timer.py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):

        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(510, 129)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame"))
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.yearlabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.yearlabel.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yearlabel"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.yearlabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.monthfromcomboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.monthfromcomboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("monthfromcomboBox"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.monthfromcomboBox, 1, 2, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.SearchButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.SearchButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SearchButton"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.SearchButton, 2, 4, 1, 2)
        self.yearfromcomboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.yearfromcomboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("yearfromcomboBox"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.yearfromcomboBox, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.dayfromcomboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.dayfromcomboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dayfromcomboBox"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.dayfromcomboBox, 1, 4, 1, 2)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        Dialog.setTabOrder(self.yearfromcomboBox, self.monthfromcomboBox)
        Dialog.setTabOrder(self.monthfromcomboBox, self.dayfromcomboBox)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.yearlabel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Year", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Day", None))
        self.SearchButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Go", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Month", None))
```

The corresponding python code is,

```
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from timer import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QTabWidget, QWidget,
                     QStyle, QStyleFactory)
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        style = QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks')
        app.setStyle(style)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.SearchButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.search)

        months = range(1,13)
        for iitem in months:
            Months = str(iitem)
            self.ui.monthfromcomboBox.addItem(Months)

        days = range(1,32)
        for iitem in days:
            Days = str(iitem)
            self.ui.dayfromcomboBox.addItem(Days)



        years = range(2010, 2017)
        for iitem in years:
            Years = str(iitem)
            self.ui.yearfromcomboBox.addItem(Years)


     def search(self):
             nowyear = int(self.ui.yearfromcomboBox.currentText())
             nowmonth = int(self.ui.monthfromcomboBox.currentText())
             nowday = int(self.ui.dayfromcomboBox.currentText())

             nowdate = int('%d%d%d' %(nowyear,nowmonth,nowday))
             print nowdate

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = Window()
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why not change it here: `nowdate = int('%d%d%d' %(nowyear,nowmonth,nowday))` Also, why do you need it as an integer, maybe  use `mktime()` to make it a more universal value, i.e. time since epoch https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.mktime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_int = 201011
date = datetime.strptime(str(date_int), '%Y%m%d')
print '{},{},{}'.format(date.year, date.month, date.day)
```

> 2010,1,1

Comment: That's great. However how could I turn X = '{},{},{}'.format(date.year, date.month, date.day) into an integer to use as follows: ("BATS.L", "yahoo", datetime(X), datetime(2016,8,8)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
dateNum = 201011

dateNum = str(dateNum)

year = dateNum[:4]
monthDay = dateNum[4:]

if len(monthDay) == 2:
    day = monthDay[1:]
    month = monthDay[:1]

print(year + "," + month + "," + day)
```

This will output:

```
2010,1,1
```

The only problem with this code is that you cannot determine dates such as:

2014111 which should be November 1st but could also be January 11th

Is there any way you can change the format to include leading zeros? (e.g. 20141101 for Nov 1st 2014)

Maybe someone else has a way to determine this. However I think logically the format makes it impossible to determine one or the other.

This code is redefined to handle the leading zeros:

```
dateNum = 20100101

dateNum = str(dateNum)

year = dateNum[:4]
monthDay = dateNum[4:]

day = monthDay[2:]
month = monthDay[:2]

print(year + "," + month + "," + day)
```

> 2010,01,01

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to convert your date parts into a string and then to an single integer if you don't actually need that integer for something. Get rid of this line:

```
nowdate = int('%d%d%d' %(nowyear,nowmonth,nowday))
```

And instead use the individiual date components however you want. It could be as simple as `print nowyear, nowmonth, nowday` (which will print them separated by spaces), or you could do something more complicated like using them to create something from the `datetime` module which you can use later (or print in a wide variety of formats).

To get the output you specifically request (`'2010,1,1'`), you can keep it pretty close to your existing code. Just use `print '%d,%d,%d' % (nowyear, nowmonth, nowday)`, or if you want to use the newer `str.format` syntax, `print '{:d},{:d},{:d}'.format(nowyear, nowmonth, nowday)`. If you wanted the single-digit month or days to use two characters (so they're always the same width), you could use `%02d` or `{:02d}` in the format strings, to request zero-padding to a width of two.